# Error in updating same value to database

Tags: php, mysql, oop

This is my database connection using OOP, please tell me what wrong in my     execute function, whenever I give update with same value it will throw 
error.

```
<?php

class db{

private $conn;
private $host;
private $user;
private $password;
private $dbname;
private $port;
private $debug;
function __construct($params=array())
{
    $this->conn = false;
    $this->host = "localhost";
    $this->user = "root";
    $this->password = "mysql";
    $this->dbname = "icecreams";
    $this->port = "";
    $this->debug = true;
    $this->connect();
}

function __destruct()
{
    $this->disconnect();
    // TODO: Implement __destruct() method.
}

function connect(){
    if(!$this->conn){
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname",$this->user,$this->password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>'SET NAMES utf8'));
                }
                catch (Exception $e){
            die('Errer :'.$e->getMessage());
        }
        if(!$this->conn){
                    $this->status_fatal = true;
                    echo 'Connection BDD failed';
                    die();
        }
        else{
            $this->status_fatal = false;
        }
    }
    return $this->conn;
}
function disconnect(){
    if($this->conn){
        $this->conn = null;
    }
}
 function execute($query){
    if(!$response = $this->conn->exec($query)){
        echo 'PDO::errorInfo()';
        echo '</br>';
        echo 'error SQL:'.$query;
        die();
    }
    return $response;
}}
```

if I update with a different value it will update, and if i give update with same value it show PDO::error info and error SQL: form execte function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your update query dont affect any rows the return of ->exec($query) is 0.
`0` is the same as `false` in conditions with "!" checks.

You can use "=== false" in your if condition:

```
if(($response = $this->conn->exec($query)) === false){
```